# What is the name of a type of question where the answer is different for every person?

Tags: single-word-requests

For example;
You're at the doctor: the doctor asks, "On a scale of 1-10 how would you rate your pain?"The answer varies from person to person, but how can the doctor judge the accuracy of the number given, which is after all subjective? Can he correlate the number with an objective measure of the pain? If I say 3, but from his experience with my type of injury he believes it should be an 8, what can he determine?
Another type of question could be, "Do you like this new shirt I bought?" or, "How do you feel about me moving to Australia?" They're all questions but the answer depends on how the person is feeling.
Share your thoughts on this!

Comment: Very subjective?

Comment: How can it be different for every person if the scale is 1-10 and there are more than 10 people?

Comment: It's not clear whether you're looking for a word or you ranting about people's differing perceptions of pain.

Comment: The answer is "a grading scale".  There are grading scales for pain, depression, etc. However, discussing whether they are flawless or not, is off topic here.

Comment: Different people have different *pain thresholds*.  I think maybe this is the term you were looking for. But I'm voting to close.  Look at the help pages to learn how to write a well-posed question, please.

Comment: I think this is more a question of measurement theory. There may be some jargon to pull out of there. The term "subjective" is used in everyday speech.